# Featherlight.JS : Does the gallery have buttons

Tags: featherlight.js

I'm looking at adding a small slim lightbox to a wordpress masonry video/photo gallery that I am building using ACF.

featherlight looks fairly simple but the demo with the gallery extension doesnt appear to have visible buttons for scrolling? You can scroll through images using swipe and arrow keys but there are no buttons to do this? Am I understanding this correctly? That seems like a weird design choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the buttons will not show on touch aware devices, but can be shown with a single CSS rule.

Comment: Thank you! :) I'm using a Microsoft Surface so that's probably why stuff isn't showing up. Thanks!